# Database design - unique data from multiple sources

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table that stores information about pictures for automobiles. In a nutshell it contains the fields 'id', 'auto_id', 'name', and 'path'. So it is linked to a particular automobile entry through the 'auto_id' field.

Now consider that I want to add pictures for houses. Would it be better to just create another table similar to this one, or add a field in the existing table to point out the type of picture it is? Or is there an altogether better way to address this type of issue?

Edit: I apologize for the wording. It's obviously a simple problem, I just don't know how to best form it into a coherent question. Thanks for the patience and any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would just model your picture table as:

```
id name path
```

and have a join table `subjects` table:

```
picture_id subject_id subject_type
```

Where `picture_id` is a FK to pictures, and `subject_id` is a FK to the specific subject deemed by `subject_type`(automobile, house etc)

Answer (score 1):

Well, now given also that:

> The 'id' field was just a unique identifier for the picture. The
>      'auto_id' field was the foreign key
>      for the automobile the picture was
>      linked to.
>
> I would like to have it set up to
>   where one can have as many photos
>   linked to cars or houses as one would
>   like.

My suggested solution is:
[image: data model]

Where

- `picture` is your original pictures table, only that `auto_id` now is `subject_id`.
- `subject` is your original automobiles table, now it will store both cars and houses records. Add a new field `type_id` as foreign key to subject types table.
- `subject_type` is a new table where you'll store all possible subjects (not limited to cars and houses only, thinking to future expansion of your subject types).

(Sorry if this diagram doesn't reflect your real number/name/datatype of tables/columns, it's just that I don't know that info)

Answer (score 0):

Given that only the subject (car or house) is what varies, and maybe in a future you will want to increase the number of subjects, I suggest you to keep all in one single table, just adding an extra field to store photo subject.

BTW: what is the difference between `id` and `auto_id` fields? <strike>If there is none, I'd suggest to get rid of `auto_id` column</strike>

Comment: The 'id' field was just a unique identifier for the picture. The 'auto_id' field was the foreign key for the automobile the picture was linked to.

Comment: hmmm, but if `auto_id` is foreign key to a cars table, it changes a little the situation: in that case I'd move that column to cars table and change it to store photo id (being thus foreign key to pictures table), so it won't interfere with houses records in pictures table.

Comment: But that way wouldn't you be limited to one photo per car? I would like to have it set up to where one can have as many photos linked to cars or houses as one would like.

Comment: OK, please update question with all said (an other missing) restrictions, with a complete question it'll be easier for us to find a suitable solution, more accurate than mine.